# NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass while reindexing the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

Hi I am getting NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass in Categorization.rb file  while reindexing the data.

The code is in rails

Categorization.rb

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable auto_index: false do
text :title, stored: true, boost: Knome::Constants::Boost::NAME
text :description, stored: true, boost: Knome::Constants::Boost::DESCRIPTION
text :user do
  user.full_name
end
integer :co_owner_ids, multiple: true do
  added_co_owners
end
integer :status do
  nil
end
time :created_at
time :updated_at
end
end


User.rb

def full_name
"#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

I have migrated the data but still getting same error.
So please help me with this.

Thankyou

Comment: User.rb is a model with method name full_name

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling method full_name, before defining it.

Define it earlier and then move down the code which is calling it.